# SSAS control the base measure at different date level

Tags: ssas

Hi I have one base measure called "receivable amount" which is at date level and makes no sense if we aggregate at month or year level.

I am trying to use Scope function to define and use different aggregation at different date level. 
For example, if it's at date level I want to apply sum aggregate and if it's at month level, i would like to sum of last date of the month and apply similar thing for year level.

Could you please help set up different aggregation using SCOPE function ? or is it the right function to use to solve this case?

```
Scope(
       {
         [Measures].[Sale Amount],
         [Measures].[Payment Amount],
         [Measures].[Receivable Amount]
       }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to do this with SCOPE.  I would do this in the underlying tables.